# Caching and Ajax CalendarExtender Confilct,

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-ajax

When i applied Caching on a Textbox which has a  Ajax calendarExtender .It raise's Error 
Thanks To firebug for showing  Error

```
syntax error
[Break On This Error] <!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHT.../xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-    transitional.dtd">


Sys.Extended is undefined
[Break On This Error]     $create(Sys.Extended.UI.CalendarBe...et("ctl00_cphDetails_TxtDateFrom"));
```

Why Its Giving This error When i used Cahing.Without Caching it Working Fine

Comment: can you post the HTML please?